# How to send data through a futures Stream by writing through the io::Write trait?

Tags: stream, rust, future

I have a function that takes a `&mut io::Write` and I'd like to use it to send a streaming response from the actix-web server without having to buffer the whole response. The function is "pushing" the data, and I can't change the function (that's the whole premise of this question) to use async streams or other kind of polling.

Currently I'm forced to use `&mut Vec` (which implements `io::Write`) to buffer the whole result and then send the `Vec` as the response body. However, the response may be large, so I'd rather stream it without buffering.

Is there some kind of adapter that would implement `io::Write`, with writes blocking as necessary in response to backpressure, and be compatible with types that actix-web can use for responses (e.g. `futures::Stream`)?

```rust
fn generate(output: &mut io::Write) {
    // ...
}

fn request_handler() -> Result<HttpResponse> {
    thread::spawn(|| generate(/*???*/));
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().body(/*???*/))
}
```

`std::sync::mpsc` and `futures::mpsc` have either both ends async, or both ends blocking, so it's not obvious how to use them as an adapter between sync and async ends.

Comment: Is it a third-party function, which you can not alter? Otherwise you could add "checkpoints" to it, buffering a part of the response into a Vec then flushing it into the [response stream](https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.7.19/actix_web/enum.Body.html#variant.Streaming) at a "checkpoint".

Comment: The `BodyStream` is a wrapper around `futures::Stream`, so this still leaves a question of transforming push-based `io::Write` into pull-based `Stream`.

Comment: Why? You could use a [MPSC](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/sync/mpsc/index.html), push your buffers in the mpsc, if it's full then pause the execution until it's ready to be pushed again. Again: this would only work if you're able to split that function into smaller parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. The key piece is [`futures::sink::Wait`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/sink/struct.Wait.html):

> A sink combinator which converts an asynchronous sink to a **blocking sink**.
>
> Created by the `Sink::wait` method, this function transforms any sink into a blocking version. This is implemented by blocking the current thread when a sink is otherwise unable to make progress.

All that is needed is to wrap this type in a struct that implements `io::Write`:

```
use futures::{
    sink::{Sink, Wait},
    sync::mpsc,
}; // 0.1.26
use std::{io, thread};

fn generate(_output: &mut io::Write) {
    // ...
}

struct MyWrite<T>(Wait<mpsc::Sender<T>>);

impl<T> io::Write for MyWrite<T>
where
    T: for<'a> From<&'a [u8]> + Send + Sync + 'static,
{
    fn write(&mut self, d: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let len = d.len();
        self.0
            .send(d.into())
            .map(|()| len)
            .map_err(|e| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, e))
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        self.0
            .flush()
            .map_err(|e| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, e))
    }
}

fn foo() -> impl futures::Stream<Item = Vec<u8>, Error = ()> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(5);

    let mut w = MyWrite(tx.wait());

    thread::spawn(move || generate(&mut w));

    rx
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible. Actix-web manages its own write buffer and socket.

Comment: I believe you've misread the question (I've updated it in an attempt to be more clear). The OP doesn't want to have access to Actix' write buffer or socket.