# How can I use futures::stream::StreamExt::for_each with error handling in the callback?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I have this piece of code which is supposed to serialize a `futures::stream::Stream` to a `Write`. I want this code to return `Err` if `write_all` fails, but I don't see a way to get that out of the callback to `for_each`. I found [How to send data through a futures Stream by writing through the io::Write trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708392/how-to-send-data-through-a-futures-stream-by-writing-through-the-iowrite-trait), but I don't understand how to make it work in my situation.

```
use std::io::Write;
use std::error::Error;
use futures::stream::StreamExt;

pub async fn download(url: &str, mut dest: impl Write) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let byte_stream = reqwest::get(url).await?.bytes_stream();
    
    byte_stream.for_each(|bytes| {
        if let Ok(bytes) = bytes {
            dest.write_all(&bytes).expect("failed to write");
        }
        futures::future::ready(())
    }).await;

    Ok(())
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json", "stream"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
futures = "0.3"
bytes = "1"
```

Comment: It appears that you are doing sync IO in an async program. [That's a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932137/155423).

Comment: I might try using `reqwest::Response::bytes` to skip the stream stuff, then save to disk in a tokio blocking task as your other linked answer shows.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use [`StreamExt::next`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/prelude/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.next) and write the loop out a bit more manually:

```rust
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use std::{error::Error, io::Write};

pub async fn download(url: &str, mut dest: impl Write) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut byte_stream = reqwest::get(url).await?.bytes_stream();

    while let Some(bytes) = byte_stream.next().await {
        let bytes = bytes?;
        dest.write_all(&bytes)?;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Notes:

1. These is [`TryStreamExt::try_for_each`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/prelude/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.try_for_each) which can be used here, but it wants to take ownership of `dest` so I went in a different direction.
2. Mixing synchronous IO (`std::io::Write`) and asynchronous IO (`reqwest`) is a bad idea without taking special care, which is not demonstrated in this answer.

See also:

- [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932137/155423)